# GKE autoscaling doesn't scale

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I am setting up a Kubernetes cluster on Google using the Google Kubernetes Engine. I have created the cluster with auto-scaling enabled on my nodepool.
[image: nodepool_setup]

As far as I understand this should be enough for the cluster to spin up extra nodes if needed.

But when I run some load on my cluster, the HPA is activated and wants to spin up some extra instances but can't deploy them due to 'insufficient cpu'. At this point I expected the auto-scaling of the cluster to kick into action but it doesn't seem to scale up. I did however see this:
[image: error]
So the node that is wanting to be created (I guess thanks to the auto-scaler?) can't be created with following message: **Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 8.0 in region europe-west1.**

I also didn't touch the auto-scaling on the instance group, so when running **gcloud compute instance-groups managed list**, it shows as 'autoscaled: no'

So any help getting this autoscaling to work would be appreciated.

TL;DR I guess the reason it isn't working is: Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 8.0 in region europe-west1, but I don't know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really have debugged it yourself already. You need to edit the [Quotas on the GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED). Make sure you select the correct project. Increase all that are low: probably addresses and CPUs in the zone. This process is semi automated only, so you might need to wait a bit and possibly pay a deposit.

Comment: Scaling the 'in_use addresses' quota solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: strange that i checked this and all my quotas are under 40%